# Bootstrap navbar hamburger menu not responding after click

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, navbar

When I view my website on mobile, though the hamburger menu appears, it doesn't respond after clicking. I am not sure what's wrong with my code.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand wc" href="{{url_for('main.home')}}">our association</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="list" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('main.about')}}">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc dropbtn navb-it" href="#">stuff1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="#">stuff2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle wc navb-it" href="#" id="navbarDropdown">Event</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2020 Hackathon</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coding Challenges</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('posts.new_post')}}">New Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('users.user_drafts', username=current_user.username)}}">My Drafts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('users.user_posts', username=current_user.username)}}">My Posts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('users.account')}}">Account</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('users.logout')}}">Logout</a>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('users.login')}}">Log in</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link wc navb-it" href="{{url_for('users.register')}}">Register</a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

At the beginning it didn't appear at all, that was because I didn't add a bootstrap color scheme to the navbar. Now, even though it shows, the menu bar in the mobile view doesn't work when clicking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand how the Navbar toggler works. It uses the [Bootstrap collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/) component.

The `data-target` attribute is set the element that you want to toggle. In this case you have it set to `list`, but there is no `list` element in the HTML. Instead set it to the id or class of the element(s) you want to toggle.